# Calling Jest spyOn on function passed as props

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I have an onSubmit function passed as props to a child component.

How would I spy on it? This is one of the things I have tried

```
const onSubmitMock = jest.fn()

  const wrapper = shallow(
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmitMock} />
  )

  const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), onSubmitMock);
```

I get

Cannot spy the function mockConstructor() {return fn.apply(this, arguments);} property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

I tried

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'onSubmit');
```

and the same thing happended.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expect(onSubmitMock ).toHaveBeenCalled();` directly after simulating submit event.

You are getting error probably because spyOn returns jest.fn()
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname

Comment: this wouldn't work, because I want to simulate the click on the input type submit button to fire the event, not simulating the event directly, and wrapper.find('input[type="submit"]').simulate('click') does not work

Comment: Are you able to `console.log(wrapper.instance()[onSubmitMock])` and see if it exists. Also method name passed to the spy it seems to need to be string `const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'onSubmitMock');`